# pass Data from a List View (generated from Rest Api) to another activity and save that into SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-intent

I am creating an android app (still the basic structure, without any design) from an Job site through XML feed using REST api.

Till now, I could managed to parse the XML data, displaying the List View with an POP UP menu item on each row.  I am passing Data from PostBaseAdapter to MarkAsFav class. Could You please tell me if I am doing right or not? coz, I am getting no any data saved in database
Now, I have a problems:

I have 3 pop up menu item:
1. Set as Favourite
2. Share on Fb
3. email to Your friend

I am working on point number-1.

For now,I would be saving the data in SQLite Database itself. so, I am passing all the data (all the details about the job with all rows) to another activity, more over I am accepting a user given name to save the details through insertDB() in my Database.

But, unfortunately , nothing is getting saved in the database . 
Can you tell me, if the data is getting passed or not and if the datas are being saved in database or not?

Please help me out. Please tell me where and how to modify the code?

DBHelper.java

```
    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME ="MyDB.db";
    public static final String JOBS_TABLE_NAME = "favourites";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_HEADER="header";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_COMPANY="company";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_CITY="city";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_STATE="state";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_COUNTRY="country";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATEDLOCATION="formatedLocation";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_SOURCE="source";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_DATE="date";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_SNIPPET="snippet";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_URL="url";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_ONMOUSEDOWN="onmousedown";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_LATTITUDE="lattitude";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_LONGITUDE="longitude";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_JOBKEY="jobkey";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_SPONSORED="sponsored";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_EXPIRED="expired";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATTEDLOCATIONFULL="formattedLocationFull";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATTEDRELATIVETIME="formattedRelativeTime";
    private HashMap hp;

    public DBHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "create table" + JOBS_TABLE_NAME  +
                        "("+JOBS_COLUMN_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "+JOBS_COLUMN_HEADER+" text, "+JOBS_COLUMN_NAME+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_COMPANY+" text, "+JOBS_COLUMN_CITY+" text, "+JOBS_COLUMN_STATE+" text, "+JOBS_COLUMN_COUNTRY+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATEDLOCATION+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_SOURCE+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_DATE+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_SNIPPET+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_COMPANY+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_URL+"text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_ONMOUSEDOWN+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_LATTITUDE+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_LONGITUDE+"text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_JOBKEY+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_SPONSORED+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_EXPIRED+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATTEDLOCATIONFULL+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATTEDRELATIVETIME+" text)"
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS favourites");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertContact(String header, String name,String company,String city,String state,String country,String formattedLocation,String source,String date,String snippet,String url,String onmousedown,String lattitude,String longitude,String jobkey,String sponsored,String expired, String formattedLocationFull,String formattedRelativeTime)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        //contentValues.put("id",id);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_HEADER,header);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_COMPANY, company);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_CITY, city);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_STATE, state);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_COUNTRY, country);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATEDLOCATION, formattedLocation);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_SOURCE, source);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_DATE, date);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_SNIPPET, snippet);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_URL, url);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_ONMOUSEDOWN, onmousedown);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_LATTITUDE, lattitude);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_JOBKEY, jobkey);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_SPONSORED, sponsored);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_EXPIRED, expired);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATTEDLOCATIONFULL, formattedLocationFull);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATTEDRELATIVETIME, formattedRelativeTime);

        db.insert("favourites", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }

    public Cursor getData(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from favourites where id="+id+"", null );
        return res;
    }

    public int numberOfRows(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, JOBS_TABLE_NAME);
        return numRows;
    }

    public boolean updateContact (Integer id, String name)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);

        db.update("favourites", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteContact (Integer id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("favourites",
                "id = ? ",
                new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts()
    {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from favourites", null );
        res.moveToFirst();

        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(JOBS_COLUMN_NAME)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
}
```

MarkAsFav.java

```
public class MarkAsFav extends Activity {

    private DBHelper mydb;

    TextView header;

    int id_To_Update = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mark_fav_layout);
        header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

        mydb = new DBHelper(this);

        Intent extras = getIntent();
        if (extras != null) {
            int Value = extras.getIntExtra("id",0);

            if (Value > 0) {
                //means this is the view part not the add contact part.
                Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
                id_To_Update = Value;
                rs.moveToFirst();

                String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.JOBS_COLUMN_NAME));

                if (!rs.isClosed()) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                header.setText((CharSequence) nam);
                header.setFocusable(false);
                header.setClickable(false);

            }
        }
    }


    public void run(View view) {
        Intent extras = getIntent();
        if (extras != null) {

            int val = extras.getIntExtra("id",0);
            String value1 = extras.getStringExtra("title");
            String value2=  extras.getStringExtra("company");
            String value3=  extras.getStringExtra("city");
            String value4=  extras.getStringExtra("state");
            String value5=  extras.getStringExtra("country");
            String value6=  extras.getStringExtra("formattedLocation");
            String value7=  extras.getStringExtra("source");
            String value8=  extras.getStringExtra("date");
            String value9=  extras.getStringExtra("snippet");
            String value10=  extras.getStringExtra("url");
            String value11=  extras.getStringExtra("onmousedown");
            String value12=  extras.getStringExtra("lattitude");
            String value13=  extras.getStringExtra("longitude");
            String value14=  extras.getStringExtra("jobkey");
            String value15=  extras.getStringExtra("sponsored");
            String value16=  extras.getStringExtra("expired");
            String value17=  extras.getStringExtra("formattedLocationFull");
            String value18=  extras.getStringExtra("formattedRelativeTime");

            String headerValue = header.getText().toString();
            Log.e("ERROR", "Inside run and checking Value and val");
            if (val > 0) {
                /*if (mydb.updateContact(id_To_Update, header.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Log.e("ERROR", "update error");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else {*/
                if (mydb.insertContact(headerValue, value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,value11,value12,value13,value14,value15,value16,value17,value18)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("ERROR", "insert contact errors");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PostBaseAdapter.java

```
public class PostBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<Result> resultList;
    private MainActivity mActivity;
    private Context mContext;
    String TAG="";


    public PostBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Result> resultList) {
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.resultList = resultList;
        this.mContext= context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Result getItem(int i) {
        return resultList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        final int j=i;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_post, null);
            //viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            viewHolder= new ViewHolder();
            //View overFlow = convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_overflow);
            viewHolder.tvTitle =   (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            viewHolder.imageClick= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_overflow);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            //overFlow.setOnClickListener(new OverflowSelectedListener(mContext, mActivity));

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final Result result = resultList.get(i);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(result.getJobtitle());
        final String jobTitle=resultList.get(i).getJobtitle();
        final String company= resultList.get(i).getCompany();
        final String city=    resultList.get(i).getCity();
        final String state=   resultList.get(i).getState();
        final String country= resultList.get(i).getCountry();
        final String formattedLocation= resultList.get(i).getFormattedLocation();
        final String source=resultList.get(i).getSource();
        final String date= resultList.get(i).getDate();
        final String snippet= resultList.get(i).getSnippet();
        final String url=     resultList.get(i).getUrl();
        final String onmousedown= resultList.get(i).getOnmousedown();
        final String lattitude= resultList.get(i).getLattitude();
        final String longitude= resultList.get(i).getLongitude();
        final String jobkey=   resultList.get(i).getJobkey();
        final String sponsored= resultList.get(i).getSponsored();
        final String expired= resultList.get(i).getExpired();
        final String formattedLocaionfull= resultList.get(i).getFormattedLocation();
        final String formattedRelativeTime= resultList.get(i).getFormattedRelativeTime();



        try {


            viewHolder.imageClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.id_overflow:

                            final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
                            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
                            // Force icons to show

                            popup.show();
                            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                    int id_To_Search = j + 1;


                                    /*Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,MarkAsFav.class);

                                    intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                                    mContext.startActivity(intent);*/
                                    switch (item.getItemId()) {


                                        case R.id.email_whatsapp:
                                            doEmailOrWhatsapp(mActivity);
                                            return true;

                                        case R.id.share_on_fb:
                                            shareOnFb(mActivity);
                                            return true;

                                        case R.id.mark_as_fav:
                                            //viewHolder.
                                          //dataBundle.putString("name", result.getJobtitle());
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,MarkAsFav.class);
                                            intent.putExtra("id",0);
                                            intent.putExtra("title", jobTitle  );
                                            intent.putExtra("company",company );
                                            intent.putExtra("city", city);
                                            intent.putExtra("state",state   );
                                            intent.putExtra("country",country );
                                            intent.putExtra("formattedLocation",formattedLocation );
                                            intent.putExtra("source",source );
                                            intent.putExtra("date", date);
                                            intent.putExtra("snippet", snippet);
                                            intent.putExtra("url", url);
                                            intent.putExtra("onmousedown",onmousedown );
                                            intent.putExtra("lattitude", lattitude);
                                            intent.putExtra("longitude",longitude );
                                            intent.putExtra("jobkey", jobkey);
                                            intent.putExtra("sponsored",sponsored );
                                            intent.putExtra("expired", expired);
                                            intent.putExtra("formattedLocationFull",formattedLocaionfull );
                                            intent.putExtra("formattedRelativeTime",formattedRelativeTime );

                                            //intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                                            mContext.startActivity(intent);
                                            return true;
                                        default:
                                            break;
                                    }

                                    return true;
                                }
                            });
                            //popup.show();
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                }
            });


        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }



    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle;//, tvPublishDate;
        ImageView imageClick;
      /* public ViewHolder(View item) {
            tvTitle = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);*/
           // imageClick=(ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.id_overflow);
           // tvPublishDate = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvPublishDate);
        }

    }
```

mark-fav-layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="370dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" >
        </EditText>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:onClick="run"
            android:text="@string/save" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Result.java

public class Result {

```
 public String jobtitle;
    public String company;
    public String city;
    public String state;
    public String country;
    public String formattedLocation;
    public String source;
    public String date;
    public String snippet;
    public String url;
    public String onmousedown;
    public String lattitude;
    public String longitude;
    public String jobkey;
    public String sponsored;
    public String expired;
    public String formattedLocationFull;
    public String formattedRelativeTime;
    public String getJobtitle() {
        return jobtitle;
    }
    public void setJobtitle(String jobtitle) {
        this.jobtitle = jobtitle;
    }
    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getFormattedLocation() {
        return formattedLocation;
    }
    public void setFormattedLocation(String formattedLocation) {
        this.formattedLocation = formattedLocation;
    }
    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }
    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getSnippet() {
        return snippet;
    }
    public void setSnippet(String snippet) {
        this.snippet = snippet;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String getOnmousedown() {
        return onmousedown;
    }
    public void setOnmousedown(String onmousedown) {
        this.onmousedown = onmousedown;
    }
    public String getLattitude() {
        return lattitude;
    }
    public void setLattitude(String lattitude) {
        this.lattitude = lattitude;
    }
    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
    public String getJobkey() {
        return jobkey;
    }
    public void setJobkey(String jobkey) {
        this.jobkey = jobkey;
    }
    public String getSponsored() {
        return sponsored;
    }
    public void setSponsored(String sponsored) {
        this.sponsored = sponsored;
    }
    public String getExpired() {
        return expired;
    }
    public void setExpired(String expired) {
        this.expired = expired;
    }
    public String getFormattedLocationFull() {
        return formattedLocationFull;
    }
    public void setFormattedLocationFull(String formattedLocationFull) {
        this.formattedLocationFull = formattedLocationFull;
    }
    public String getFormattedRelativeTime() {
        return formattedRelativeTime;
    }
    public void setFormattedRelativeTime(String formattedRelativeTime) {
        this.formattedRelativeTime = formattedRelativeTime;
    }
    public String getDetails() {
        String result = jobtitle + ": " + company + "\n" + city + "-" + state
                + "\n" + country + "\n" + formattedLocation +"\n" + source+"\n"+date+
                "\n"+snippet+"\n"+url+"\n"+onmousedown+"\n"+lattitude+"\n"+longitude+"\n"
                +jobkey+"\n"+sponsored+"\n"+expired+"\n"+formattedLocationFull+"\n"+formattedRelativeTime;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is way too much code. Make the smallest reproducible example. Get data from a fixed string and pass it to SQL

Comment: @sixtytrees thanks for your reply. Could You please check the PostDatabase class and MarkAsFab class and  DBHelper class let me know if I am doing right or not. Still I am not getting any data saved in database.

Answer (score 0):

I have just updated my code and its working fine for me. I am posting it here ,so that anyone can use if needed.

MarkFav.java

```
public class MarkAsFav extends Activity {

    private DBHelper mydb;

    TextView header;

    int id_To_Update = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mark_fav_layout);
        header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

        mydb = new DBHelper(this);
        mydb.getWritableDatabase();

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int value = extras.getInt("id");

            if (value > 0) {
                //means this is the view part not the add contact part.
              /*  Cursor rs = mydb.getData(value);
                id_To_Update = value;
                rs.moveToFirst();

                String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));

                if (!rs.isClosed()) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                header.setText( nam);
                header.setFocusable(false);
                header.setClickable(false);*/

            }
        }
    }


    public void run(View view) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {

            int value     =   extras.getInt("id");
            String headerValue = header.getText().toString();
            String value1 =   extras.getString("title");
            String value2 =   extras.getString("company");
            String value3 =   extras.getString("city");
            String value4 =   extras.getString("state");
            String value5 =   extras.getString("country");
            String value6 =   extras.getString("formattedLocation");
            String value7 =   extras.getString("source");
            String value8 =   extras.getString("date");
            String value9 =   extras.getString("snippet");
            String value10=   extras.getString("url");
            String value11=   extras.getString("onmousedown");
            String value12=   extras.getString("lattitude");
            String value13=   extras.getString("longitude");
            String value14=   extras.getString("jobkey");
            String value15=   extras.getString("sponsored");
            String value16=   extras.getString("expired");
            String value17=   extras.getString("formattedLocationFull");
            String value18=   extras.getString("formattedRelativeTime");


            Log.e("ERROR", "Inside run and checking Value and val");
            if (value > 0) {
                /*if (mydb.updateContact(id_To_Update, header.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Log.e("ERROR", "update error");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else {*/
                if (mydb.insertContact(headerValue, value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,value11,value12,value13,value14,value15,value16,value17,value18)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("ERROR", "insert contact errors");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB.db";
    public static final String JOBS_TABLE_NAME = "favourites";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_HEADER="header";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_COMPANY="company";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_CITY="city";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_STATE="state";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_COUNTRY="country";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATEDLOCATION="formatedLocation";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_SOURCE="source";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_DATE="date";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_SNIPPET="snippet";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_URL="url";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_ONMOUSEDOWN="onmousedown";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_LATTITUDE="lattitude";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_LONGITUDE="longitude";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_JOBKEY="jobkey";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_SPONSORED="sponsored";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_EXPIRED="expired";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATTEDLOCATIONFULL="formattedLocationFull";
    public static final String JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATTEDRELATIVETIME="formattedRelativeTime";
    private HashMap hp;


    public DBHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
    }

    @Override
   /* public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "create table" + JOBS_TABLE_NAME  +
                        "("+JOBS_COLUMN_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "+JOBS_COLUMN_HEADER+" text, "+JOBS_COLUMN_NAME+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_COMPANY+" text, "+JOBS_COLUMN_CITY+" text, "+JOBS_COLUMN_STATE+" text, "+JOBS_COLUMN_COUNTRY+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATEDLOCATION+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_SOURCE+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_DATE+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_SNIPPET+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_COMPANY+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_URL+"text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_ONMOUSEDOWN+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_LATTITUDE+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_LONGITUDE+"text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_JOBKEY+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_SPONSORED+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_EXPIRED+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATTEDLOCATIONFULL+" text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATTEDRELATIVETIME+" text)"
        );*/
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "create table" + JOBS_TABLE_NAME  +
                        "("+JOBS_COLUMN_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "+JOBS_COLUMN_HEADER+" Text, "+JOBS_COLUMN_NAME+" Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_COMPANY+" Text, "+JOBS_COLUMN_CITY+" Text, "+JOBS_COLUMN_STATE+" Text, "+JOBS_COLUMN_COUNTRY+" Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATEDLOCATION+" Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_SOURCE+" Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_DATE+" Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_SNIPPET+" Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_COMPANY+" Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_URL+"Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_ONMOUSEDOWN+" Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_LATTITUDE+" Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_LONGITUDE+"Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_JOBKEY+" Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_SPONSORED+" Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_EXPIRED+" Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATTEDLOCATIONFULL+" Text,"+JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATTEDRELATIVETIME+" Text)"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS favourites");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertContact(String header, String name,String company,String city,String state,String country,String formattedLocation,String source,String date,String snippet,String url,String onmousedown,String lattitude,String longitude,String jobkey,String sponsored,String expired, String formattedLocationFull,String formattedRelativeTime)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db =  this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        //contentValues.put("id",id);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_HEADER,header);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_COMPANY, company);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_CITY, city);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_STATE, state);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_COUNTRY, country);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATEDLOCATION, formattedLocation);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_SOURCE, source);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_DATE, date);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_SNIPPET, snippet);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_URL, url);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_ONMOUSEDOWN, onmousedown);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_LATTITUDE, lattitude);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_JOBKEY, jobkey);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_SPONSORED, sponsored);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_EXPIRED, expired);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATTEDLOCATIONFULL, formattedLocationFull);
        contentValues.put(JOBS_COLUMN_FORMATTEDRELATIVETIME, formattedRelativeTime);

        db.insert("favourites", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }

    public Cursor getData(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from favourites where id="+id+"", null );
        return res;
    }

   /* public int numberOfRows(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, JOBS_TABLE_NAME);
        return numRows;
    }*/

    public boolean updateContact (Integer id, String name)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);

        db.update("favourites", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteContact (Integer id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("favourites",
                "id = ? ",
                new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts()
    {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from favourites", null );
        res.moveToFirst();

        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(JOBS_COLUMN_NAME)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
}
```